# Can I patch a string value in a kubernetes configmap?

Tags: kubectl, patch, configmap

Trying to patch a string value in the data section of a kubernetes config map but running into an error.

```
kubectl patch configmap cm-example -n example-ns -p '{"data":{"application.yml":{"keycloak":{"auth-server-url":"https://server-url.domain.com/auth/"}}}}'
```

Getting the below error

```
The request is invalid: patch: Invalid value: "map[data:map[application.yml:map[keycloak:map[auth-server-url:https://server-url.domain.com/auth/]]]]": unrecognized type: string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue when I tried to run a patch on my configmap map that holds a file that was supposed to be a yaml file.

The thing is, deployment, pod, jobs - they are yaml or json. BUT a file inside the config map is just a string. The patch will not know what to do and you will need to send the entire string, which is not very useful. Another thing to do is try a `sed`. But it does not give the same experience as running a patch on pod, deployment and so on - files that are really yaml or json.

Comment: yeah thats the issue I appear to be having. I ended up using sed, thanks @Danilo

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61824987/9524565). Here, you can run `kubectl get configmap`, run the `sed` command and finally run `kubectl apply` command as mentioned in Step 3 in the above answer.