# kubectl edit multiple configmaps

Tags: kubectl, configmap

I have a setup where I have multiple configmaps (with a common prefix). How do I edit all (or some) of them using a single command?
Use case is, I have a common field in all of them which I want to edit.

I tried `kubectl edit configmap prefix*` and `kubectl edit configmap prefix.*`. Didn't work.

Comment: There is no such command or way to edit the multiple config files using a common key name in kubectl but as per this [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/1028) we can use kustomize which is a configuration tool that allows you to customize Kubernetes resources by using overlays, rather than modifying the original resources directly. Refer to this [blog](https://opensource.com/article/21/6/kustomize-kubernetes) by Redhat for information on kustomize and modifying the config files.

Comment: If you wish to update a single config file then refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989943/kubectl-update-configmap) which has multiple solutions.

Comment: Are the above comments helped you ? I am happy to assist if you have any further queries

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes does not have a built in feature to achieve this, however you can use a script like below to edit multiple configmaps.

#!/bin/bash

configmaps=("configmap1" "configmap2" "configmap3")

for cm in "${configmaps[@]}"; do
kubectl edit configmap "$cm"
done