# How to update Secrets (Without Deleting and Creating) in Openshift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a folder in my server that I want to update inside a cointaier in a pod. How do I do that without deleting the Secret?

I know that the following creates my secret:

`oc create secret generic privkey --from-file=/opt/privkey`

I know that the following deletes the secret:

`oc delete secret generic privkey`

Is there a way to do that without deleting?
I am fine if I have to delete the pod.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update k8s ConfigMap or Secret without deleting the existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216278/update-k8s-configmap-or-secret-without-deleting-the-existing-one)

Comment: Yes, it’s a duplicate. Did not see this one. Apologies

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this:

```
oc create secret generic privkey --from-file=/opt/privkey --dry-run -o yaml | oc replace -f -
```

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks. I thought that a solution could be writing the yml file. the `-o` with `replace` works great

Comment: For newer openshift/OKD versions, when "oc replace -f -" is no longer working, use "oc apply -f -"