# Changing environment variables from inside of pod to openshift

Tags: python, bash, automation, openshift, devops

I want to change a environment variable of openshift from inside a pod.

The thing I want to change is Bearer token, as that will get expired within a day or so, and changing it manually is not possible on n numbers of environment. So I want to change the value of the environment variable using a script inside the pod.

I am stuck and want some guidance regarding this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't change an env variable of a running process from outside of that process.

Comment: I want to change the secrets variable of openshift from inside a pod. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an oc or curl command inside the container to do this. Ofcource your container image has to contain the oc or curl command.
If your value is stored in a secret see, [How to update Secrets (Without Deleting and Creating) in Openshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50637582/how-to-update-secrets-without-deleting-and-creating-in-openshift)

See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/authentication/ldap-syncing.html. It describes how to run an oc command within a container.