# kubectl cp for config files and pod destruction

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

Some of our services in our K8s (EKS) envirnment use config files to drive functionality so we don't have to redeploy the whole image each time.  Using `kubectl cp` command allows us to copy new config files to the pod.  So the command `kubectl cp settings.json myapi-76dc75f47c-lkvdm:/app/settings.json` copies the new `settings.json` file to the pod.

For fun I deleted the pod and k8s recreated it successfully with the old `settings.json` file.  Anyone know a way of keeping the new `settings.json` file if the pod gets destroyed?  Is there a way to update the deployment without redeploying the image?

Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the config file inside a ConfigMap and mount the ConfigMap to Deployment's pod template. When the file needs updating, either:

1. Re-create the ConfigMap (kubectl delete then kubectl create --from-file)
2. Or use the "dry-run kubectl create piped into kubectl replace" technique from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38216458/34586

Comment: I figured there was a solution,  I wasn't sure if Configmaps were the prefered way of doing this.  Thanks much!